# Пропал Genymotion из списка устройств Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

Сегодня возникла довольно странная ситуация - пропал эмулятор из списка доступных устройств в студии. Не могу понять в чем проблема. Переустановил AS, переустановил полностью Genymotion, добавил повторно плагин genymotion а все-равно не вижу никакких устройств в списке. Думал проблема в sdk - доставил sdk. Дальше переустановил устройство, и все-равно пусто. Не могу понять в чем проблема.

### UPDATE

Судя по всему у меня не может запустится устройство в genymotion, хотя не понятно почему раньше он запускался.

Comment: Этот вопрос может быть странным, но тем не менее, его я должен задать. Вы включаете эмулятор, когда собираетесь запустить рабочий код?)

Comment: @SonicMyst, что значит включаю? Вы думаете я ищу эмулятор в списке не запустив его предварительно?)

Comment: я спросил, потому что такая возможность существует, к тому же вы не указали весь процесс ваших действий. А насколько я помню, сам по себе он не видит(могу ошибаться) пока не врубить эмулятор(хотя может там плагин есть какой-то).

Comment: стандартный эмулятор же отлично работает. зачем вам Genymotion)

Comment: @SonicMyst, я эмулятор запускаю))) просто как-то странно все происходит

Comment: @Cypher, у меня отлично работал и этот, но он сломался почему-то)